# LINQ OrderBy on inner object's property

Tags: linq

Below are the hierarchies and the required function

```
public class Friend
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Now the required function:

```
public List<string> WhatsApp(List<Friend> friends)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

I need to get the list of friend names in descending order of there message time stamp. Just like Whats App or any other IM for that matter.

I am getting a feeling that this can be done in 1 or 2 lines using LINQ but since I am new to LINQ, unable to drill down the problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Which message would you want to take the timestamp from, given that there could you many of them or none? Have you read any LINQ tutorials yet?

Comment: I have gone through OrderBy function but as soon as I traverse till Messages.Time, Friend.Name value is lost. So, I am not getting the list of Friend.Name. Sorry if I did not explain it precisely. I need to get the list of friend names in descending order of message time. The friend(say A) who sent message most recently comes first and then the one who sent message before A...

Comment: So you're actually ordering friends by the *latest* message in Messages? You might want to work out how to get "the date/time of the latest message" (hint: Max) and order by that. But you should also consider friends who haven't sent any messages.

Comment: Let say all friends in the input list have sent one and only one message. How we can go till Message.Time. If I do 'friends.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Message.Time)', compiler will not allow me to write 'Message.Time'

Comment: Well no, because there's no `Message` property, is there? You'd need `x.Messages[0].Time` or similar. If you want to start with the simple scenario where each friend has exactly one message, you might want to model it that way, with a `public Message Message { get; set; }` property instead of your `Messages` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the idea is to order by the last (i.e. max) message timestamp, the following should do the job:

```
return friends.OrderByDescending(f => f.Messages.Max(m => (DateTime?)m.Time))
    .Select(f => f.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Casting to `DateTime?` is needed to avoid exception when there are no messages for some friend.

In general when you need to order the parent having multiple children by something based on children properties, it should be some aggregate value (like `Sum`, `Count`, `Min`, `Max` etc.).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, this is working as expected. However, I did not understand why Max is behaving like sorting. Why it is sorting Messages list. It should give Message with maximum time stamp. That means Max should give single object. If possible, please throw some light on this.

Comment: Yes, Max returns a single value from the related messages for each Friend. Then you sort the Friends by that value. Imagine the Friend has a property called `LastMessageTime` and you sort by that.